# "Run destination iOS Device is not valid" for iPod Touch running 3.1.3 with XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipod-touch

I'm trying to test my application against a friend's old iPod touch running iOS 3.1.3.

I have XCode 4 and receive this error message when trying to run the application:

> **The run destination iOS Device is not valid for Running the scheme
>   'MyApp'.**
>
> The scheme 'MyApp' contains no buildables that can be built for the
>   architectures supported by the run destination iOS Device. Make sure
>   your targets build for architectures compatible with the run
>   destination iOS Device.

I have set the deployment target to iOS 3.1.3. What else do I need to do in XCode 4 to build and test the app on this old iPod touch?

I am using the "standard" build architecture, not optimised.

Comment: Is the device provisioned for development?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved this by Autocreating schemes (Scheme > Manage schemes > Autocreate schemes) and then selecting the iPod Touch instead of "iOS Device" which had appeared in the schemes. D'oh!

Comment: Worked for me, although everything was set correctly (I did not have to choose the device, just had to press "Autocreate schemes").

Comment: This answer also works for most of us: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16050803/6776960

Answer (score 3):

In my Target->General, I selected Device "iPad" and was trying to run in an iPhone simulator. I just changed the Device option to universal (which was alright for me) and then run again. It solved my problem.