# The run destination [user's] iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta

After successfully running apps, so many times on my iPhone, I am getting this error again and again. Any solution?[image]

Comment: Make sure you selected device is `iPhone` under deployment info section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Scheme > Manage schemes > Autocreate schemes  may resove your problem

Answer (score 6):

Try restarting your Xcode. It worked for me. Got this issue while working on Xcode 9.4 (Beta)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16050803/3251886

Comment: Definitely worked for me more than the other answers!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: From Xcode top tool bar Click on **Product->Scheme->New Scheme.**

Step 2: Create new scheme by entering your scheme name.

Step 3: Set the current scheme as target scheme by ***clicking on Set The active scheme icon which is located just right to the stop button icon in xcode***.

Step 4: Clean the solution and run it.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue in Xcode 10.
It was a bug in XCode, I closed and reopened Xcode and it started working.

I've noticed this sort of thing many many times now with Xcode with other problems, its very frustrating  for me.